# Lyapunov exponents for a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of a disk for which the boundary is not attracting

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Let $D$ be an $n$-dimensional disk (considered a $C^{\infty}$ manifold-with-boundary), and let $\partial D$ denote its boundary.  Assume that $f \colon D \to D$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism having the following property:

> **For each $x \in D \setminus \partial D$ its $\omega$-limit set, $\omega(x)$, is not fully contained in $\partial D$** (the possibility that $\omega(x) \cap \partial D \ne \emptyset$ is not excluded).

Let $\mu$ be an ergodic invariant probability measure supported on $\partial D$.  By the Oseledets theorem, there are $n-1$ (counting multiplicity) Lyapunov exponents on the tangent bundle of $\partial D$, and the "remaining" Lyapunov exponent (corresponding to directions transverse to $\partial D$; call it the *external Lyapunov exponent* for $\mu$).

The question is:

> **Is the external Lyapunov exponent nonnegative, for each $\mu$?**

**Comment.**  When $f$ is $C^{1 + \alpha}$ with $\alpha > 0$, Pesin's theory of invariant measurable families of submanifolds gives a positive answer.  I do not know what happens if $f$ is $C^1$ only.